# PrepareForSegue Tableview issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have an issue with segue when clicking on cell and trying to transfer my date to DetailViewController

I didn't find here answers to my question, so I am asking here.

Here is my Method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

//    NSLog(@"Source Controller = %@", [segue sourceViewController]);
//    NSLog(@"Destination Controller = %@", [segue destinationViewController]);
//    NSLog(@"Segue Identifier = %@", [segue identifier]);


        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       if (indexPath){
        lastNews *item = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:item];
        NSLog(@"%@", item.title);

   }

}
```

if I will remove if condition only
and leave my code like this one:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    //    NSLog(@"Source Controller = %@", [segue sourceViewController]);
    //    NSLog(@"Destination Controller = %@", [segue destinationViewController]);
    //    NSLog(@"Segue Identifier = %@", [segue identifier]);


            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            lastNews *item = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:item];
            NSLog(@"%@", item.title);



    }
```

my data can be transferred but only always first cell.

If I will implement it like this one:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailNews"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       //if (indexPath){
        lastNews *item = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:item];
        NSLog(@"%@", item.category);

   }

}
```

it will send but always a title of news and always from first news. (NSLOG only for checking)

I know it receives all values, I have checked it by NSLOG, not only the title.

For your information I have always latest 20 news parsed from web site
That's working and my cells filled by news titles.

Could you please suggest me where I am wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if "sender" is the cell that's calling this, you can do:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForCell:sender];
lastNews *item = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[segue.destinationViewController setDetail:item];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this and got the same. only title of first news sending but, according to my NSLOG I did get nothing in detail view controller. my slog says all null: 2013-04-18 20:50:12.972 IsraelNews[42293:c07] (null)
`2013-04-18 20:50:12.984 IsraelNews[42293:c07] (null)
2013-04-18 20:50:12.985 IsraelNews[42293:c07] (null)
2013-04-18 20:50:12.985 IsraelNews[42293:c07] (null)
2013-04-18 20:50:12.985 IsraelNews[42293:c07] (null)
2013-04-18 20:50:12.986 IsraelNews[42293:c07] (null)`

Comment: I think Now it's working but partly. I just send it to my method setDetail, but did anything there. now it's getting data but still only first news from the my 20. any cell I click and it's return me only first news.

Comment: Ok I think I solved my last issue. I have forgotten connect my IBOUTLET Tableview to my viewcontroller. That's it – Anton just now edit

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I solved my last issue. I have forgotten connect my IBOUTLET Tableview to my viewcontroller. That's it